# Promtail to create new label based on the selector

Tags: logging, grafana-loki, promtail

I’m new to Loki and trying to deploy it on our non-prod cluster. I’m able to push the logs and visualize the logs in Grafana. I have a requirement where I need to get the part of the logs(containing a work) and make it available under a new label.
Unfortunately I’m not able to get the configuration working.

```
pipeline_stages:
- match:
   selector: '{app="web-app"} |= "analytics"'
   stages:
     - labels:
       app: web-app-analytics
```

Please advice.

> **Loki version: 2.3.0**
>
> **Promtail version: 2.3.0**

Comment: Did you solve this? ... I'm having the same problem:

`    - match:
        selector: '{job="varlogs"} |= "error"'
        stages:
        - labels:
            log_level: "error"`

Comment: No, I was not able to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace "labels:" directive by "static_labels:".

Thomas